# Find Shortcut Path Vbs

Tags: vbscript, wmi

I am looking for a VBS browse function which gets the shortcut path. Unfortunately all browse functions I tried got only the folder path, but not shortcut path. I can see the shortcut in the dialog, but cannot get the path of it.

Is there someone who has this kind of function?

```
strComputer = "."
Const ALL_OPTIONS = &H4000

Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set objFolder = objShell.BrowseForFolder (0, "Select a folder:",ALL_OPTIONS,(16))

If objFolder Is Nothing Then
    Wscript.Quit
Else
    Set objFolderItem = objFolder.Self
End If

objPath = objFolderItem.Path
```

This function gives a real folder path, but when I select a shortcut with it, it returns `null`.

How can I get the shortcut path with browse for folder function?

Comment: I can understand nothing, please explain more about your specific problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use the .ShortPath property of the file or folder object:

```
Option Explicit

Dim goFS : Set goFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim f
Set f = goFS.GetFolder(".") : WScript.Echo f.Path, f.ShortPath
Set f = goFS.GetFile(WScript.ScriptFullName) : WScript.Echo f.Path, f.ShortPath
```

output:

```
cscript //nologo "45388073-pi pa po.vbs"
C:\Users\eh\work C:\Users\eh\work
C:\Users\eh\work\45388073-pi pa po.vbs C:\Users\eh\work\453880~1.VBS
```

**Update wrt comment:**

given:

```
objPath = objFolderItem.Path ' it's a string not an object!
```

sShortPath, and `goFS`, do:

```
sShortPath = goFS.GetFolder(objPath).ShortPath
```

Comment: I added some more explanation .